# How do I import an .AVI movie into 3d matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, movie, avi

I am trying to write a function that imports an .AVI file and returns a 3D matrix in MATLAB.

Ultimately, this is so I can perform an fftn on the 3d matrix.

Comment: None at all, how far have you got ?  You did do some work on the problem before you posted this question, didn't you ?  Tell us what you did and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote

% this is basically for gray scale video

function video3d

carobj=mmreader('carwide.avi');
% the carwide.avi is video considered for making it   %  matrix

nFrames=carobj.NumberOfFrames;

M=carobj.Height;                    % no of rows

N=carobj.Width;                     % no of columns

video=zeros(M,N,nFrames,'uint8');   % creating a video 3d matrix

for k= 1 : nFrames

```
im= read(carobj,k);

im=im(:,:,1);           % all three layers will have same image

video(:,:,k)=im;
```

end

end

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [VIDEOREADER class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/videoreaderclass.html).